# Getting a list of available bluetooth devices using react-native-ble-manager

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

How can I get a list of available bluetooth devices using [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager)?

Answer (score 7):

1. First you should:

   ```
   import BleManager from 'react-native-ble-manager';
   ```

   and don't forget:

   ```
   import { NativeAppEventEmitter } from 'react-native'
   ```
2. Then, inside of your component (I'm doing on `componentDidMount`):

   2.1. Add Handle to `NativeAppEventEmitter` on `'BleManagerDiscoverPeripheral'` event:

   ```
   NativeAppEventEmitter.addListener('BleManagerDiscoverPeripheral',(data) => 
       {
         console.log(data) // Name of peripheral device
       });
   ```

   2.2. Start your BleManager manager:

   ```
   BleManager.start({showAlert: false});
   ```

   2.3. `BleManager.scan([], 30)` where first value is an array if service UUID, second is seconds how long scan will run

You can find primitive example on the official lib's page [react-native-ble-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ble-manager)

Comment: I'm doing the same but it not showing me list of buletooth on device near me

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you find any solution  of this issue..??

Answer (score 7):

I recently had to use this library and this is what worked for me:

```
import { NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter } from 'react-native';
import BleManager from 'react-native-ble-manager';

const BleManagerModule = NativeModules.BleManager;
const bleManagerEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(BleManagerModule);

...

state = {
  peripherals: new Map(),
};

componentDidMount() {
  BleManager.start({ showAlert: false })

  this.handlerDiscover = bleManagerEmitter.addListener(
    'BleManagerDiscoverPeripheral',
    this.handleDiscoverPeripheral
  );

  this.handlerStop = bleManagerEmitter.addListener(
    'BleManagerStopScan',
    this.handleStopScan
  );

  this.scanForDevices(); // I chose to start scanning for devices here
}

scanForDevices() {
  BleManager.scan([], 15);
}

handleDiscoverPeripheral = (peripheral) => {
  const { peripherals } = this.state;

  if (peripheral.name) {
    peripherals.set(peripheral.id, peripheral.name);
  }
  this.setState({ peripherals });
};

handleStopScan = () => {
  console.log('Scan is stopped. Devices: ', this.state.peripherals);
}
```

EDIT: DON'T FORGET TO ASK PERMISSION FOR LOCATION!

Answer (score 0):

For scanning nearby devices use below code,

```
scanNearByDevices(serviceUUIDList, duration, isAllowDuplicates) {
bleManager
  .scan(serviceUUIDList, duration, isAllowDuplicates)
  .then(results => {
    console.log('Scanning...');
    // this.setState({scanning: true});
  });
}
```

After that use below code to get discover device list,

```
getDiscoverdDevices() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 bleManager
    .getDiscoveredPeripherals()
    .then(devices => {
      console.log('Discovered devices:', devices);
      this.deviceMap.set(device.id, device);
      }
      resolve(devices);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error fail: ', error);
      reject(error);
    });
});
}
```

**If you are running your application on android then make sure you have given location permission to your application**